# Find combinations of two digits

Tags: combinatorics

I am in a puzzle that which is generated by one of my friend .

She gave me last 4 numbers of her mobile phone & i want to find the first 6 numbers.

I guessed the first 4 letters.

Assume that AAAA is the first 4 letters and MMMM is the last 4 letters and XX is the 2 letters after the first 4 letters .

So her number is 10 digit soit would be AAAAXXMMMM

I know AAAA and MMMM and now i have to find XX .

I know getting the exact value is impossible but i think that i can get the combinations of XX [2 digits].

How can i get this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply formula of permutations with repetition .

So , number of permutations in this particular case is given by :

$N=10^2$

Comment: ok how can i calculate this ?

Comment: @DileepDil,You can only calculate number of possible solutions which is $100$

Comment: yeah,i am really poor in maths..i need the combinations...not 100.

Comment: @DileepDil,Then write them all..$00,01,02...$ , etc .

Comment: Pardon me if i am making some troubles,but is there any calculator or something that which i can generate those numbers ?